# How to keep fixed number of connections

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, network-programming, threadpool

I am new to Java but not new to general programming.

Scenario is that I can have maximum of n connections at a time and opening and closing a connection is very costly.

I want to reuse same n connections and want to keep something in Collection.

When a request comes, I pick it up connection, do my work and return connection without closing. When next request comes, I pick up next available connection.

When all connections are in used and a request comes, then I just wait for connection to be available.

What will be the most cleanest java solution. I dont need the code, I just need some ideas to explore. May be some framework already does it, may be some java classes already provide that functionality.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Connection to what?

Comment: Something like connection pooling DB provides ....

Comment: These are socket connections to some outside server

Comment: So, you have a n connections. Put a connection handler that distributes the connections. If none are available queue it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with Connection Pooling. In this, if you are using the Connection for multiple tasks, write them separately put them in the pool.
Get the connection from the pool when it's required. Then push it back to the pool, when it's completed. By this way, the Connection will be thread safe and inconsistency can be avoided.
Also, opening and a closing connection will lead to resource crunch.

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework such as HTTP Core NIO or Netty to do this. For an example instance HTTPCore NIO you can create a worker thread group to connect to a back end as below.

```
ProxyConnPool connPool = createConnectionPool(connectingIOReactor);
connPool.setMaxTotal(100);
connPool.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

private static ProxyConnPool createConnectionPool(final ConnectingIOReactor connectingIOReactor)
                                                                                                    throws KeyManagementException,
                                                                                                    KeyStoreException,
                                                                                                    NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                                                                                    CertificateException,
                                                                                                    FileNotFoundException,
                                                                                                    IOException {
        ProxyConnPool proxyConnPool = null;

        if (SECURE_BACKEND) {
            clientSSLContext =
                               SSLUtil.createClientSSLContext(TRUST_STORE_LOCATION,
                                                              TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD);

            BasicNIOConnFactory connectionFactory =
                                                    new BasicNIOConnFactory(
                                                                            clientSSLContext,
                                                                            null,
                                                                            ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT);

            proxyConnPool = new ProxyConnPool(connectingIOReactor, connectionFactory, 5000);
        } else {
            proxyConnPool = new ProxyConnPool(connectingIOReactor, ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT);
        }

        return proxyConnPool;
    }
```

You may find my sample code for [HTTP core NIO reverse proxy](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/HTTPCoreNIORP/tree/master/HTTPCoreReverseProxy) and [Netty reverse Proxy](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/NettyReverseProxy)

In Netty the code looks something similar to this.

```
// Configure the bootstrap.
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

> When a request comes, I pick it up connection, do my work and return connection without closing. When next request comes, I pick up next available connection.

I would use a simple `BlockingQueue<Connection>` that is shared by all of your threads.

```
final BlockingQueue<Connection> connectionQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Connection>();
```

At the start of your application you would open up a bunch of `Connection` objects and add them to the queue.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CONNECTIONS_TO_START; i++) {
    queue.put(new Connection());
}
```

When a thread goes to get a connection it would get a `Connection` from the queue, waiting for one if none were immediately available.  After it used the `Connection` it would return it to the queue for the next thread to have.

```
// this will wait if there are no connections available
Connection connection = queue.take();
try {
   useTheConnection(connection);
} finally {
   // after we are done add it back to the queue
   queue.put(connection);
}
```

The tricky part to all of this is when you get some sort of network exception on the socket.  Your thread would need to properly close the `Connection` and then add a new one to the queue.  Maybe something like:

```
// this will wait if there are no connections available
Connection connection = queue.take();
try {
   useTheConnection(connection);
} catch (Exception e) {
   // assume the connection is bad
   try {
      connection.close();
   } catch (Exception e2) {
      // ignore any exceptions here
   }
   // start a new fresh connection to add back to our queue
   connection = new Connection();
} finally {
   // after we are done add it back to the queue
   queue.put(connection);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Executor Service with fixed number of threads

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
```

You can create a class Connection which will create a connection object and return it

```
class Connection implements Callable<Connection> {

    @Override
    public Connection call() {
        // Logic to get the connection
        return new Connection();
    }
}
```

Then do submit the task and get Future object of Connection from the Pool.

```
Future<Connection> future = service.submit(new Connection());
Connection conn = future.get();
```

Comment: It's wasteful to start threads just to create connections, and there is nothing here that will pool them.